# nrow() gives more rows than original in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have a file with 20 fields as headers in the first row. The remaining rows have unequal number of fields, some of the rows have more columns than the headers. When i tried to read it using read.delim(), it reads the data without error but the total row count is more than the original number.

Here are a few lines of the file:

```
Chromosome   Position    SNPid   Reference   Alternate   QUAL    Homozygosity    Tool    Depth   MappingQuality  EFFECT  IMPACT  FUNCTIONAL_CLASS    CODON_CHANGE    AMINO_ACID_CHANGE   GENE_NAME   GENE_BIOTYPE    GENE_CODING     TRANSCRIPT_ID   EXON_ID    
chr1    403111  .   G   A   24  het SAM 20  55  INTERGENIC  MODIFIER    _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
chr1    602567  rs21953190  A   G   3265.77 hom GATKSAM 91  58.46   SYNONYMOUS_CODING   LOW SILENT  gaT/gaC D1034   ADNP2   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000008  5   _
chr1    604894  rs21953191  A   G   2869.77 hom GATKSAM 77  59.70   NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING   MODERATE    MISSENSE    Ttt/Ctt F259L   ADNP2   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000008  5   _
chr1    758630  .   T   TC  1531.73 hom GATKSAM 38  46.20   INTRON  MODIFIER    _   _   _   PQLC1   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000011  2   _
chr1    800715  .   C   CT  514.73  hom GATKSAM 13  60.00   INTRON  MODIFIER    _   _   _   PQLC1   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000011  6   ,SPLICE_SITE_ACCEPTOR   HIGH    _   _   _   PQLC1   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000011  7   ,SPLICE_SITE_DONOR  HIGH    _   _   _   PQLC1   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000011  6   _
chr1    1104035 rs21966859  G   A   3803.77 hom GATKSAM 97  57.97   INTRON  MODIFIER    _   _   _   NFATC1  protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000013  2   ,INTRON MODIFIER    _   _   _   NFATC1  protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000036234  2   _
chr1    1120994 .   CGCG    C   604.73  hom GATKSAM 21  56.55   INTERGENIC  MODIFIER    _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   ,UPSTREAM   MODIFIER    _   _   _   NFATC1  protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000013  _   ,UPSTREAM   MODIFIER    _   _   _   NFATC1  protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000036234  _   _
chr1    1136916 rs21935602  G   A   3899.77 hom GATKSAM 101 59.17   DOWNSTREAM  MODIFIER    _   _   _   ATP9B   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000000014  _   ,DOWNSTREAM MODIFIER    _   _   _   ATP9B   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000042968  _   ,UTR_3_PRIME    MODIFIER    _   _   _   ATP9B   protein_coding  CODING  ENSCAFT00000046825  29  _
```

There are 9 rows in the file.But when it is read in R and the number of rows are counted it shows as 12.

```
read.delim("test.txt",header=T,sep='\t')->data
nrow(data)
```

Could someone help, to read the data properly?

Below is the output from dput(data)

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Chromosome = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("HIGH", "MODIFIER", "chr1"
), class = "factor"), Position = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 9L), .Label = c("1104035", "1120994", 
"1136916", "403111", "602567", "604894", "758630", "800715", 
"_"), class = "factor"), SNPid = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c(".", "_", "rs21935602", 
"rs21953190", "rs21953191", "rs21966859"), class = "factor"), 
Reference = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "C", "CGCG", "G", "T", "_"), class = "factor"), 
Alternate = structure(c(1L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "ATP9B", "C", "CT", "G", "NFATC1", 
"PQLC1", "TC"), class = "factor"), QUAL = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("1531.73", 
"24", "2869.77", "3265.77", "3803.77", "3899.77", "514.73", 
"604.73", "protein_coding"), class = "factor"), Homozygosity = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("CODING", 
"het", "hom"), class = "factor"), Tool = structure(c(6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("ENSCAFT00000000011", 
"ENSCAFT00000000013", "ENSCAFT00000036234", "ENSCAFT00000042968", 
"GATKSAM", "SAM"), class = "factor"), Depth = structure(c(4L, 
9L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 11L), .Label = c("101", 
"13", "2", "20", "21", "38", "7", "77", "91", "97", "_"), class = "factor"), 
MappingQuality = structure(c(5L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 
12L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 3L), .Label = c(",SPLICE_SITE_DONOR", ",UPSTREAM", 
",UTR_3_PRIME", "46.20", "55", "56.55", "57.97", "58.46", 
"59.17", "59.70", "60.00", "_"), class = "factor"), EFFECT = structure(c(4L, 
8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("", 
"DOWNSTREAM", "HIGH", "INTERGENIC", "INTRON", "MODIFIER", 
"NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING", "SYNONYMOUS_CODING"), class = "factor"), 
IMPACT = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("", "LOW", "MODERATE", "MODIFIER", 
"_"), class = "factor"), FUNCTIONAL_CLASS = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"MISSENSE", "SILENT", "_"), class = "factor"), CODON_CHANGE = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"Ttt/Ctt", "_", "gaT/gaC"), class = "factor"), AMINO_ACID_CHANGE = structure(c(7L, 
3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"ATP9B", "D1034", "F259L", "NFATC1", "PQLC1", "_"), class = "factor"), 
GENE_NAME = structure(c(6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("", "ADNP2", "ATP9B", "NFATC1", "PQLC1", 
"_", "protein_coding"), class = "factor"), GENE_BIOTYPE = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"CODING", "_", "protein_coding"), class = "factor"), GENE_CODING = structure(c(6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"CODING", "ENSCAFT00000000011", "ENSCAFT00000036234", "ENSCAFT00000046825", 
"_"), class = "factor"), TRANSCRIPT_ID = structure(c(8L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"29", "6", "ENSCAFT00000000008", "ENSCAFT00000000011", "ENSCAFT00000000013", 
"ENSCAFT00000000014", "_"), class = "factor"), EXON_ID = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"2", "5", "6", "_"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
",DOWNSTREAM", ",INTRON", ",SPLICE_SITE_ACCEPTOR", ",UPSTREAM", 
"_"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Chromosome", "Position", 
"SNPid", "Reference", "Alternate", "QUAL", "Homozygosity", "Tool", 
"Depth", "MappingQuality", "EFFECT", "IMPACT", "FUNCTIONAL_CLASS", 
"CODON_CHANGE", "AMINO_ACID_CHANGE", "GENE_NAME", "GENE_BIOTYPE", 
"GENE_CODING", "TRANSCRIPT_ID", "EXON_ID", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Just FYI, `read.delim` already has `header` and `sep` set to your chosen values. Go with `data = read.delim("test.txt")` in the future. Also do `dput(data)` or `head(data)` to give a better idea of your data.

Comment: What happens if you call ncol() on it? tail()? It would be helpful to have more information about what the dataframe looks like. Also, probably best to avoid calling your variable "data", since that is a built in r function

Comment: I would double-check (1) all whitespace between fields is really tabs, not spaces; (2) no loose quotation characters floating around (or set `quote=""`). It would be great to post the data file somewhere publicly accessible.

Comment: here is the link to the sample file: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3581360c62f3f9449993080447c4a371cf11dccab

Comment: @user1779730 Use `dput(data)` or `head(data)` and copy-paste the output here instead of uploading a whole data file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your data in different rows have different number of fields. That is the reason you cannot read your data properly.

Comment: @rmk please have a look at the modified question for dput(data)

Answer (score 2):

R thinks you have 21 rather than 20 fields per line (maybe there are trailing tabs on each line?), and your lines 6-9 have additional fields:

```
 count.fields("test.txt",sep="\t")
## [1] 21 21 21 21 21 41 31 41 41
```

This confuses the heck out of `read.delim`, which tries to guess what's going on from the first 5 lines (it shouldn't, but that's the way it is).  You might think you could use `fill=TRUE` to get around this, but you can't.

I tried using `colClasses` along with `fill=TRUE` to specify the field types (I used `colClasses=rep("character",41)` but you can probably guess better than that), but it doesn't seem to work, probably because your header only has 21 columns.

The `fread` function in the `data.table` package can do a little better, but only if you tell it not to try to guess the format from lines after #5, and it discards the data in columns beyond 21.

```
library(data.table)
nrow(fread("test.txt",autostart=5))  ## 9
```

Hmm, even that doesn't quite work as expected (it doesn't pick up the header properly, even if I set `header=TRUE`, probably because column 21 doesn't have a header field ... The bottom line is that you probably have to figure out what those extra fields are and do something more explicit with them (e.g. add header fields ...)

Basically, R expects your data to be pretty clean. It might be worth sending this example to the maintainer of the `data.table` package, who is trying to make `fread` be as robust as possible ... this would represent a challenge.

Comment: As a work around, could you use `skip` and `nrows` to read in the file in two pieces after inspecting it with `count.fields`, and the join them together via `rbind.fill`?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the data you can see that it is highly "mutated" with many fusion lines. These are in many cases signaled by the presence of commas. I think this data is in a different format than you expect. Your first element in the dput data was a factor with Chromosome values =c("HIGH", "MODIFIER", "chr1"). That's not a sensible result, pointing to a lack of understanding on your part about the organization of the original data. You should post the original text file somewhere that can be accessed over the Internet, so the original layout can be examined. In particular the tabs you think are the delimiters are either not there or are not being captured by the SO interface.

After being pointed to the data sample, which should have been put into the question body by you doing editing, try this to delete the comments that follow the commas:

```
 datL <- readLines("~/Downloads/test.txt")
 datLred <- gsub("[,].+$", "", datL)
 read.delim(text=datLred)

> str(read.delim(text=datLred) )
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ Chromosome       : Factor w/ 1 level "chr1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Position         : int  403111 602567 604894 758630 800715 1104035 1120994 1136916
 $ SNPid            : Factor w/ 5 levels ".","rs21935602",..: 1 3 4 1 1 5 1 2
 $ Reference        : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","C","CGCG",..: 4 1 1 5 2 4 3 4
 $ Alternate        : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","C","CT","G",..: 1 4 4 5 3 1 2 1
snipped remain columns
```

Comment: Did you see the [link](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3581360c62f3f9449993080447c4a371cf11dccab) the OP left in the comments?

Comment: very nice Procrustean solution.

Comment: Procustes was the first hacker?

Comment: I think i have not understood the problem. I cannot see any commas in the original file. Could you please elaborate it.

Comment: `> grep("[,].+$",  datL) #[1] 6 7 8 9`. There were commas in lines 6,7,8 and 9 of the data in http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3581360c62f3f9449993080447c4a371cf11dccab

Comment: The grep  command removes everything after the commas which means the data after the columns is missing. Could the data be read properly without removing the data after comma?

Comment: It would need to be a two step process since you cannot mix 'tab' and 'commas' as separators for `read.table`. You might need a unique identifier, perhaps from the first portion of the data that I showed you how to import, and then merge or cbind the "extra data" back to the object you would create with the `read.delim(text=...)` call. We remain in the dark as far as a good description of the data layout. You have not been helping in this regard.

Comment: The sample data file at http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3581360c62f3f9449993080447c4a371cf11dccab gives a description of the data layout. I hope this file will help to understand the problem.

Comment: No. It doesn't. It does not explain why you have trailing extra fields in some lines but not others, and it provides no documentation, i.e. filed names and types, for those extra fields that I was calling "fusion mutants." I was hoping that by using an analogy with a genetics phenomenon that I might alert you to the difficulties with your problem specification.

Comment: @DWin some of the variants in the file have more than one annotation. In such cases the variants have extra fields without headers. Here is another sample file which does not have commas, but still gives more rows with nrow() function. Could you please help what's wrong with the file? File can be found at: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3459789aa7b38b669993184215930cd162994021f

Comment: I get some lines with 30 columns and other lines with 170 columns using tabs as the separator. You seem to be missing the point that throwing additional data at your unpaid consultants on the Internet is not solving the problem of a complete lack of a description of the data layout. Are you the researcher who is analyzing this? If not, can you get some involvement in the high level task of describing the data and the goals of this analysis?